# c# OPC client : OPCGroup.SyncWrite sometimes fails

Tags: c#, opc

I made an opc client in order to connect to Rockwell Rslinx. I used only OPCgroup.SyncRead and SyncWrite.
Everything is working fine and I write and read tags from a Rockwell plc.
To test the SyncWrite I used a sine wave and i see it correctly in the trend page of the plc.
In addition when I press a button on the form I set a value until I keep the button pressed which return to zero when I release the button (let's say a pulse).
That value is written in the PLC and I can check it in the trend the same. Then I read it back from the PLC in the form.
To do that I charge array[0] with the value of the sine wave and array[1] with the value of the pulse. Then array is passed to the SyncWrite.
So, as I said everything is OK.
But now I had to add a new functionality. This is a second order system (T(s) or second order filter).
I use the same array of course and now array[0] is the result of the filter and array[1] is again the pulse.
The pulse is read back from the PLC and is now the force perturbing the system.
In order to switch from the sine wave calculation to the filtering I use a button that enable filtering or sine wave alternatively.
Here I get crazy because when I switch to filter and press the button that generate the pulse to be read back from the plc, primarily pulse does not arrive to the PLC.
But the strangest thing is that within array[1] I see the value of the pulse. This I see in debugging when I set the point of interrupt in the line here below with the
SyncWrite

```
  public static void Write_synchr(RSIOPC r)
    {
      try
        {
          DataToSend.SetValue(r.array_to_send, 1);
          r.RSLinxOPCgroup_w.SyncWrite(1, ref r.SyncServerHandles_w, ref DataToSend, out SyncErrors2);
        }
      catch (Exception e)
        {
          MessageBox.Show(e.ToString(), "Error:  ",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }
```

Even stranger the fact that sometimes I saw it working, I do not know how, but  not always. So I tried to correct and so I came to this point.
When I was seeing it working sometimes the strategy of the sw to activate deactivate the filter or the sine wave was different but in my opinion wrong. And as a matter of fact  it was not always working.
While it was working I could see and test also the behaviour of the filter in responding to the pulse and that was fine.

Comment: I have used OPC for years, the code and management was always time consuming. I switch to using Node-Red about 2 years ago. If you would like some help with setting this up I can give you some working examples. The nice thing is you don't need to buy RsLinx anymore! I use C# for almost all of my code but Node-Red may require some JavaScript, if you don't like the idea of JavaScript then Node-Red is not for you.

Answer (score 0):

I made a lot of test and found this strange behaviour.
If I use the following

```
public float test_second_order_filter()
    {
        force[0] = ... the result of the SyncRead to read the value of the pulse ...
        filter[0] = (float) (-(filter[2] * param_filter[2] / param_filter[0]) - (filter[1] * param_filter[1] / param_filter[0]) +
                     +(force[2] * param_force[2] / param_filter[0]) + (force[1] * param_force[1] / param_filter[0]) +
                        +(force[0] * param_force[0] / param_filter[0]));
        filter[2] = filter[1];
        filter[1] = filter[0];
        force[2] = force[1];
        force[1] = force[0];
        return filter[0];
    }
```

that is exactly what I have to do but the behaviour is what described in my previous post

Then I tried with a simplified version :

```
public float test_second_order_filter()
    {
        force[0] = ... the result of the SyncRead to read the value of the pulse ...
        filter[0] = (float) (force[0] + filter[2]);
        filter[2] = filter[1];
        filter[1] = filter[0];
        force[2] = force[1];
        force[1] = force[0];
        return filter[0];
    }
```

(Formula here makes no sense) Again no way

Then I tried with this :

```
public float test_second_order_filter()
    {
        force[0] = ... the result of the SyncRead to read the value of the pulse ...
        filter[0] = (float) (force[0] + 1 + filter[2]);
        filter[2] = filter[1];
        filter[1] = filter[0];
        force[2] = force[1];
        force[1] = force[0];
        return filter[0];
    }
```

(Formula here makes no sense) Something happens and when I press the button sometimes the pulse arrives to the PLC, I see the PLC trend moving. From the ....try ... catch  error come about access violation in SyncWrite many times but code does not stop and continue doing something.

Then I tried with this :

```
public float test_second_order_filter()
    {
        force[0] = ... the result of the SyncRead to read the value of the pulse ...
        filter[0] = (float) (force[0] + 0.005 + filter[2]);
        filter[2] = filter[1];
        filter[1] = filter[0];
        force[2] = force[1];
        force[1] = force[0];
        return filter[0];
    }
```

(Formula here makes no sense) Now system is working (...Ok , with a formula that makes no sense but it works). If I press button I see the pulse in the PLC that is read back from the PLC itself within the form and so I see it reflected in force[0]. This is what I need to do but with the first code sample formula.

So it seems to me there is someting related with the float management. I cannot use the double type because both SyncRead and SyncWrite return an error.

With reference to my first post

```
public static void Write_synchr(RSIOPC r)
{
  try
    {
      DataToSend.SetValue(r.array_to_send, 1);
      r.RSLinxOPCgroup_w.SyncWrite(1, ref r.SyncServerHandles_w, ref DataToSend, out SyncErrors2);
    }
  catch (Exception e)
    {
      MessageBox.Show(e.ToString(), "Error:  ",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

}
```

In the loop I  set the value of r.array_to_send[0] with the value of filter[0] and the value of r.array_to_send[1] with the value of the pulse generated with the button in the form.

I like to remember that with the following formula I have no problem at all

```
r.array_to_send[0] = (float)(2 * Math.Cos((2 * (1.0 / Time_period[0]) * Math.PI) * t));
```

Regards

Comment: I think this is caused by RsLinx memory cache.

Comment: I suppose to have found the reason. Most probably is abaout the floating point management (there is a lot of literature about catastrophic  error occurring using floating point numbers). Probably in addition there is something in the OPCAuto.dll Rockwell wrapper (RsiOpcAuto.dll)  again with the floating point numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose to have found the reason. Most probably is abaout the floating point management (there is a lot of literature about catastrophic  error occurring using floating point numbers). Probably in addition there is something in the OPCAuto.dll Rockwell wrapper (RsiOpcAuto.dll)  again with the floating point numbers. I tried dividing by 10 the result of the filter calculation (in the PLC i then multiply by 10) and then diveded by 100, then 1000 and finally 1000'000'000 and things then got better. I told I was receiving sometimes error about some access violation within the Rockwell wrapper when executing OPCGroup.SyncWrite. When I started dividing by the power of 10 I was receiving  the error less frequently.Probably the solution is to truncate the result of any calculation, expecially when subtracting. I read that subtracting is when the approximation leads to those catastrophic errors.